# Why does GitHub ignore .gitattributes patterns that mark certain files as binary?

Tags: git, github, gitattributes

I would like to exclude some files from line count statistics on GitHub, for example *.dat files.

In .gitattributes it should be possible to do this:

`*.dat text -diff`

or

`*.dat binary`

If I commit a .dat file after committing .gitattributes with the above settings, GitHub Desktop (for Windows) correctly shows 'This binary file has changed' and does not show any diffs and does not count them in user contributions.
On GitHub.com, however, the same file is still treated as a standard source code file and all additions and deletions are counted.

You can see it in this small test repository:
https://github.com/btitze/line-count-test

Is this a bug on GitHub.com? 
I would like the *.dat files to be handled in the same way as, for example, *.png files, for which lines are never counted.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug on GitHub. It might be an interesting feature request.

Comment: There are ongoing discussions on Github/linguee, which wraps around git diff. But so far there seems no real workaround https://github.com/github/linguist/discussions/5164