# On github, is there a way to force the user to merge when specific files have changed

Tags: git, github, gitattributes

I've developed a git merge driver - basically a specialized json merge. I want to have certain file merges to fail, causing the user to merge. All of this works fine on developer machines but github pull requests allow squash merges.

I made a number of changes to .gitattributes, including unsetting the merge attrib and trying to make it look like binary:

**/mypath/*.json -merge

**/mypath/*.json -text

My preference is something like this:

**/mypath/*.json merge=AutoMergeDriver -text

I expected the merge driver to be ignored by github and the merge by github would not be allowed because it would be considered binary (by -text). And developer systems would use the driver (defined in each developers' git config). I'd still like github to be able to show diffs on the file (it currently does) - while not always valid, most of the time a github text diff would be valuable for reviewers.

Comment: "All of this works fine on developer machines but github pull requests allow squash merges." What role does this play? Merge conflicts do not disappear just because you squash merge.

Comment: Take the case where my .gitattributes has just the "-text". My testing was to push branch A to github, checkout new branch B and make a change to X.json and push branch B. Switch back to branch A, make a change to X.json in a different location and push that. Create a PR on github from B and set the destination as A. It allows the merge even though X.json should be "binary" (-text). Back on my local, in A, I merge from B, it states: warning: Cannot merge binary files: X.json

Comment: Yes, but what does it have to do with "GitHub allows squash merges"? I think GitHub simply ignores the `.gitattributes` file, regardless of merge method (merge commit or squash merge)

Comment: Well, perhaps that is the answer then, that .gitattributes is ignored. Wasn't my impression - perhaps we need to use bots or actions to accomplish it then.

Comment: What happens if you [mark the file as binary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_marking_files_as_binary) by setting `*.json -diff` or `*.json binary`? Alas, I think you need `*.json -text -merge` in a single line, not as separate lines.

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59036141/why-does-github-ignore-gitattributes-patterns-that-mark-certain-files-as-binary). After looking at that one, I tried using "binary" instead of "-text" which worked (PR shows a conflict) but does not show diffs. Going to play with the diffs attribute and see if I can get that working.

Comment: @knittl if you want to write up an answer feel free - you were on the right track with binary - what worked is: **/mypath/*.json diff merge=AutoMergeDriver binary   - I did have to repeat the test process completely with the new .gitattributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent GitHub from automatically merging the files, [mark them as `binary`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_marking_files_as_binary):

```
**/mypath/*.json binary
```

`binary` is a [*Macro attribute*](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_using_macro_attributes):

> The built-in macro attribute "binary" is equivalent to:
> `[attr]binary -diff -merge -text`

Comment: After the note that binary is a macro, I retried. Order of the attributes mattered. So what mostly worked was: **/mypath/*.json binary diff merge=AutoMergeDriver  Caveat: the diff on github was not ideal. It essentially was using "ours", not surprising since github thinks it is binary - the diff showed against the common ancestor. More important, when I resolved the conflict locally and pushed to github, the diffs were "too big", and I think it is more than just a format difference since I matched the line endings. Probably sufficient for my needs like this, otherwise look into a bot.